# How to read through file and compute win/loss chart from records given in file?

Tags: java, file

My assignment is I have to manage a soccer league.There is a soccer league (text file) that I have to import into the program.Each line of the imported file displays the outcome of a single game:the name of two teams together with the scores like

Peter 4 Tiger 3

Sky 2 Peter 0

Tiger 1 Sky 2

I have to write the program to read this text file and displays the output of team records like

Team Wins Losses

Peter 1 1

Tiger 0 2

Sky 2 0

I don't understand how to read through the lines and calculate the wins and losses associated with each team/String.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

public class SoccerLeagueStandings
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
  {
 File inFile = new File("LeagueScore.txt");
    if(! inFile.exists())
    {
      System.out.println("Error could not open the file");
    return;
    }
String Panthers="Panthers";
String Tigers = "Tigers";
String Sky = "Sky";

Scanner input = new Scanner (inFile);
int PW=0;
int PL=0;
int TW =0;
int TL = 0;
int SW=0;
int SL=0;

while (input.hasNextLine())
{
 String firstTeam=input.next();
 input.nextInt();
 int firstScore=input.nextInt();
   String secondTeam=input.next();
   input.nextInt();
   int secondScore = input.nextInt();
 if (firstScore>secondScore)
 {
   if (firstTeam.equals(Panthers))
   {
     PW+=1;
   }
   if (firstTeam.equals(Tigers))
   {
     TW+=1;
   }
   if (firstTeam.equals(Sky))
   {
     SW+=1;
   }
 }
}

}
}
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: you need to be able to understand the problem if want to be able to solve it. First you should figure out how to read input from a text file, then you need to figure out how to parse input from the file (probably by spaces), then you need to figure out how to keep track of each team's win losses

Comment: I've updated with what I've done so far, I do not know how ot keep track of each team's wins/losses

Comment: what kind of data structures are you allowed to use?

Comment: We are allowed to use arrays

Comment: It looks to me like you're halfway there.  What exactly is holding you up?

Comment: @JoeC I dont think I am counting the number of wins and losses correctly. Plus my code will not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main challenge in this problem is to keep track of the wins and losses of each team.
So i suggest to create a class called Team which holds: *name, winsCount, lossCount*. This class represents a single team along with its wins and loss count.

Create an arrayList of ***Team*** and fill it using the file content.
So your algorithm would be as the following:

1. Parse the file line by line using ***Scanner***.
2. Split each line by space in order to get the teams and their scores.
3. Compare the scores of the teams.
4. Add the winner team to the ArrayList OR increment its *winsCount* if already exist.
5. Do the same for the loser team.

Below is a non-tested sample code:

Following is the Team class:

```
public class Team {

    private String name;

    private int winsCount;
    private int lossCount;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getWinsCount() {
        return winsCount;
    }

    public void setWinsCount(int winsCount) {
        this.winsCount = winsCount;
    }

    public int getLossCount() {
        return lossCount;
    }

    public void setLossCount(int lossCount) {
        this.lossCount = lossCount;
    }

}
```

Below is how to fill the arraylist from the input file:

```
private void generateWinsLossesFromInput(String filePath)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(filePath);
    List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        String match = input.next();
        // Split the line and get teams and their scores.
        String[] splittedMatch = match.split("\\s+");
        String firstTeam = splittedMatch[0];
        int firstTeamScore = Integer.parseInt(splittedMatch[1]);
        String secondTeam = splittedMatch[2];
        int secondTeamScore = Integer.parseInt(splittedMatch[3]);

        if(firstTeamScore > secondTeamScore)
        {
            addWinner(firstTeam, teams);
            addLoser(secondTeam, teams);
        }
        else
        {
            if(secondTeamScore > firstTeamScore)
            {
                addWinner(secondTeam,teams);
                addLoser(firstTeam, teams);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void addWinner(String team, List<Team> teams)
{
    int index = 0;
    for(index = 0; index<teams.size(); index++)
    {
        Team t = teams.get(index);
        if(t.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(team))
        {
            // Team already exists, so just increment its winsCount
            t.setWinsCount(t.getWinsCount() + 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(index == teams.size())
    {
        // team not found, So add it as new team to the list.
        Team t = new Team();
        t.setName(team);
        t.setWinsCount(1);
        t.setLossCount(0);
        teams.add(t);
    }
}

private void addLoser(String team, List<Team> teams)
{
    int index = 0;
    for(index = 0; index<teams.size(); index++)
    {
        Team t = teams.get(index);
        if(t.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(team))
        {
            // Team already exists, so just increment its loss count.
            t.setLossCount(t.getLossCount() + 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(index == teams.size())
    {
        // team not found , then add new team to the list
        Team t = new Team();
        t.setName(team);
        t.setWinsCount(0);
        t.setLossCount(1);
        teams.add(t);
    }
}
```

At the end, you would be able to iterate over the array list and print out each team along with its Wins and loss counts.

Comment: We don't know how to use maps or what Parse is

Comment: You would do the same algorithm with ArrayLists, although hashmaps would be faster. Check my edited response.

Comment: If this works with you, please check this as answer in order to help others.